# Why do certain fractional values in TriangleWave not evaluate?

Tags: bugs, evaluation, special-functions, periodic-function

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

While answering another question I discovered that [`TriangleWave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TriangleWave.html) does not automatically evaluate when given certain fractional values, specifically fractions with a denominator of 20:

```
TriangleWave[ Range[8] / 20 ]
```

> ```
> {TriangleWave[1/20], 2/5, TriangleWave[3/20], 4/5, 1, 4/5, TriangleWave[7/20], 2/5}
> ```

These are reduced by `Simplify`:

```
TriangleWave[ Range[8] / 20 ] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1, 4/5, 3/5, 2/5}
> ```

This appears to be the only denominator under 10,000 that does not automatically evaluate:

```
Cases[TriangleWave[1/Range[1*^5]], _TriangleWave]
```

> ```
> {TriangleWave[1/20]}
> ```

Is there a reason to believe that this behavior is anything other than a bug in `TriangleWave`?

Comment: It only seems to evaluate when `(2 ArcSin[Sin[2 Pi t]])/Pi` is an explicit `NumberQ`

Comment: Interesting question - I've wondered sometimes how MM decides (and why) to not simplify. E.G., 4/Pi (ArcSin[Sin[2/20 Pi]]) results in a trig form, while 4/Pi (ArcSin[Sin[3/20 Pi]]) simplifies, yet both are rationals...

Comment: @rasher I have raised a question about that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40080/why-do-certain-values-in-arcsin-not-fully-evaluate).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have added the bug header. Is the introduction version correct? I don't have access to earlier version than 9.0 at the moment.

Comment: @Xavier, version 8 has the bug; since `TriangleWave[]` was introduced in version 7, testing that as well (by somebody other than you or me) should make for an accurate record.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rojo's comment is spot on. If you look at the implementation of `TriangleWave`, you'll find something like this:

```
TriangleWave[t_?NumberQ] := With[{r = 2 ArcSin[Sin[2 π t]]/π}, r /; NumberQ[r]] /; Im[t] == 0
```

Note the use of `NumberQ` in the definition, which only checks if the argument is **explicitly** a number. For certain values of your input,  `ArcSin[Sin[2 π t]]/π` is `False` for `NumberQ`:

```
{#, NumberQ@#}& /@ (ArcSin[Sin[2 π Range[8]/20]]/π) // TableForm
```

[image]

They should've used `NumericQ` instead of `NumberQ`.

Comment: How do you find the implementation?

Comment: @s0rce You can clear the attributes and look at the definitions.

Comment: @s0rce Something like this `peep[s_] := Module[{at},
  at = Attributes[s];
  ClearAttributes[s, at];
  Print@Definition@s;
  SetAttributes[s, at];
  ]; peep[TriangleWave]`

Comment: Thanks for the exploration.  It sounds like you agree that this is a bug; is that correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I agree that it is a bug.