# Why do certain values in ArcSin not fully evaluate?

Tags: functions, evaluation, symbolic, trigonometry

This is a continuation of: [Why do certain fractional values in TriangleWave not evaluate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40070/121)
The analysis by [R.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/) and [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) revealed that problem to reduce to the behavior of:

```
ArcSin[Sin[π / 10]]
```

> ```
> ArcSin[1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]
> ```

Every other denominator besides ten, at least up to 500,000, automatically evaluates to a simpler form:

```
 Position[ArcSin[Sin[π / Range[500000]]], _ArcSin]  (* slow *)
```

> ```
> {{10}}
> ```

All other coefficient of π with a denominator of ten appear to exhibit the same problem:

```
ArcSin[Sin[{1, 3, 7, 9, 11} π/10]]
```

> ```
> {ArcSin[1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])], ArcSin[1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])], ArcSin[1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5])], 
>  ArcSin[1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])], ArcSin[1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5])]}
> ```

`FullSimplify` reduces the expression:

```
 ArcSin[Sin[{1, 3, 7, 9, 11} π/10]] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {π/10, (3 π)/10, (3 π)/10, π/10, -(π/10)}
> ```

Is this a bug? Is there some explanation for it?

---

**Before someone points out the obvious**: I see that `Sin[π/10]` evaluates to `1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])`.  But why isn't `ArcSin` "smart" enough to recognize this value, when it recognizes others?  For example `Sin[π/12]` evaluates to `(-1 + Sqrt[3])/(2 Sqrt[2])` but `ArcSin` correctly recognizes this and outputs `π/12`.

Comment: Why would they give `ArcSin` `ReadProtected` if removing it does not show additional information? :(

Comment: @Jacob [A bad sense of humor?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6gzOcTNKwE)

Comment: FWIW, while `Sin[Pi/8]` does not evaluate, if expanded to `Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]]/2]`, by hand or with ``Simplify`TrigToRadicals``, `ArcSin[Sqrt[2 - Sqrt[2]]/2]` does not evaluate back to `Pi/8`, unless `FullSimplify` is applied.  This seems to have a different issue than `Pi/10`, in that `Pi/8` is never guessed at, if we apply `Trace` as in Simon Wood's answer.  (Of course, without replacing `Sin[Pi/8]`, `ArcSin[Sin[Pi/8]]` yields `Pi/8`.)

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the `Trace` of one which *does* work:

```
x = Sin[Pi/5]
(* Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8] *)

Trace[ArcSin[x], TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image]

It appears that *Mathematica* computes the `ArcSin` numerically and then recognises the result, 0.628319 as possibly equal to `Pi/5`. To check it computes `Sin[Pi/5]`, and subtracts it from the original argument to see if it gets zero. It does, and so `Pi/5` is the correct result.

Note that this relies on getting zero from this:

```
x - x
(* 0 *)
```

Interestingly, with `Pi/10` we get this:

```
x = Sin[Pi/10]
(* 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) *)

x - x
(* 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) *)
```

It doesn't automatically simplify to zero. The `Trace` reveals that *Mathematica* correctly guesses that the numerical result 0.314159 might be equal to `Pi/10` but because the result above doesn't simplify to zero it appears that the guess of `Pi/10` is rejected and the result is returned unevaluated:

```
Trace[ArcSin[x], TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. Adding a `Expand` or `Simplify` in `ArcSin` internals would have helped.

Comment: It seems to be this effects all `x - x` where `x` matches the FullForm `Times[Rational[1, n],Plus[__]]`.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Nice observation.  It seems the minus sign is applied to the `Plus` factor when the numerator of `Rational[p, q]` is `p = 1`; otherwise it is applied to `p`.  (If `p == -1`, the minus is taken from the `Rational` and moved to the `Plus` automatically.)

Comment: Kind of fun, if mysterious: `ClearAll[p]; SetAttributes[p, NumericFunction]; N[p[], prec_] := N[23 Pi, prec]; ArcSin@Sin[p[]/10]`.  `Trace` does not reveal how it's done.  You can play with the multiple of `Pi` - I always get a correct, exact answer (in terms of `p[]`).

Answer (score 2):

*Extended comment*

There seems to be an entire class that does not get simplified

```
mm = 1000;
nn = 20;
nn2 = 20;
nn3 = 10;
primes = Table[Prime[kk], {kk, mm}];
Apply[Equal, 
 Head /@ Table[
   ArcSin[1/ll (ll3 Sqrt[kk] + ll2)], {kk, primes[[;; nn]]}, {ll, 
    nn2}, {ll2, -nn2, nn2}, {ll3, -nn3, nn3}]]
```

> True

All the examples by Mr.Wizard are in this class.

I thought the issue might be that Mathematica knows that `ArcSin[Sin[Pi/20]] == Pi/20` only because `Sin[Pi/20]` stay unevaluated, but that seems not to be the reason, which can be seen from

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
 {ArcSin},
 SetAttributes[ArcSin, HoldAll];
 HoldForm@Evaluate@Column@
    {ArcSin[Sin[Pi/10]],
     ArcSin[1]}
 ]
```

> ArcSin[Sin[Pi/10]] 
>    Pi/2

which I suppose doing a simple `ArcSin[Unevaluated[Sin[Pi/10]]]` also proves.