# Mathematica not recognising closed forms as specific values

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a Mathematica program that outputs a piecewise function, and some parts of the expression are not being recognised as specific numbers when using `FullSimplify`. For example, in the output there is

```
ArcCos[3/5] + 2 ArcSec[Sqrt[5]]
```

which is actually equal to $\pi$, and there is also

```
ArcCos[3/5] - 2 ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]]
```

which is actually equal to $0$.

I was wondering if there was a way to have Mathematica recognise these sort of outputs in their more simplified form. I know that I can use numerical approximation, but was wondering if it was possible to do so while keeping the output in exact/closed form.

Comment: @Kuba Perhaps I worded my question poorly; I am saying that the two expressions **are** equal to $\pi$ and $0$ respectively, and would like the output to have $\pi$ and $0$ as opposed to the trigonometric expressions above.

Comment: @Kuba $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is not $1/\cos(x)$: N[ArcCos[3/5] - 2 ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]]] (how do I format code in answers/comments?)

Comment: @Kuba I know it does, that's why I used it in my question.

Comment: @kuba Sorry read your comment wrong, just thought it was standard notation.

Comment: No problem :) I could've assumed it is inverse function, doesn't make sense otherwise. It is good to post a pice of code instead of latex too. p.s. Welcome to Mathematica.SE :) (*I've deleted previous comments as not relevant now*)

Comment: I will do so in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40080/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Mathematica can handle this when you switch to `Exp` form of expressions:

```
ArcCos[3/5] + 2 ArcSec[Sqrt[5]] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify
ArcCos[3/5] - 2 ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> π
> 0
> ```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it looks like it will solve any potential problem of this type. However, the two examples given are the only ones I know of, so I can't test further. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work in every possible case but for your examples you could write a function doing :

```
expr1 = ArcCos[3/5] + 2 ArcSec[Sqrt[5]];
expr2 = ArcCos[3/5] - 2 ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]];

Solve[{Sin[x] == (Sin[expr1] // TrigExpand), 
       Cos[x] == (Cos[expr1] // TrigExpand), -π < x <= π}, x, Reals]
(* {{x -> π}} *)

Solve[{Sin[x] == (Sin[expr2] // TrigExpand), 
       Cos[x] == (Cos[expr2] // TrigExpand), -π < x <= π}, x, Reals]
(* {{x -> 0}} *)
```